# Return Future Message from an Actor

Tags: scala, akka, scalaz

I have an existing `API` which returns a `Future`. Now introducing an `Actor` for one of the use cases and trying to continue using same service `API` from it. From below you can see `MyService.saveValues` return future.

```
object MyActor {
   implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
   implicit val timeout = Timeout(1 second)
   case class SampleMessage(list: List[String])
   val actorSystem =  //get actorSystem that was created at the startup


  def saveMessage(list: List[String])  ={
    val res = (actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MyActor]) ? SaveMyMessage(list) ).mapTo[Future[\/[Throwable,String]]
 //res map{ r=>

 //}

 }
}
class MyActor extends Actor {
import MyActor._

def receive = {
  case SaveMyMessage(list) =>

   val originalSender = sender

   val res : Future[\/[Throwable,String] ] = MyService.saveValues(list)


   originalSender ! res
  }
}
```

As you can see in `def saveMessage` I am using `ask` to wait for a result from an actor. However `ask` also creates its own future so result (`val res`) in `saveMessage` becomes `Future[Future[T]]` which looks annoying. What's the best way to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pipeTo` forwards the result of a Future to an `ActorRef`.

```
import akka.pattern.pipe


val originalSender = sender
val res : Future[\/[Throwable,String] ] = MyService.saveValues(list)
res pipeTo originalSender
```

If `saveValues` throws, your future never complete and will end up timing something out though.

If you ever end up with `Future[Future[A]]`, but want `Future[A]` as a result of `sequencing/traversing` or something, you can always "flatMap that shit."

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val foo: Future[Future[Int]] = ???
val bar: Future[Int] = foo.flatMap(identity)
```

If you already depend on scalaz (and scalaz.contrib if on scalaz 7.0.x), you can use `join` defined in monad syntax.

```
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
import scalaz.contrib.std.scalaFuture._
val bar2: Future[Int] = foo.join
```